# Which dart HTTP client package(s) can I use to make HTTP Version 3 (HTTP/3) requests?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, http

I intend to use such a package in a Flutter Android/Ios app.
So far I have seen the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) and [http2](https://pub.dev/packages/http2) packages but none makes mention of HTTP/3.

Comment: I think you're out of luck for now. Support for HTTP3 in the dart SDK is tracked here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38595

Answer (score 1):

There are no such packages implemented in Dart language.